# How to prevent numeric conversion when importing with Import[path, "tsv"]?

Tags: import

I want to import a TSV file where many of the columns have entries like `00966`.

When I use `Import[path, "tsv"]` to import this file, such entries get converted to integers (e.g. `00966` gets read as the integer `966`).

I want instead to preserve those entries as strings.  IOW, `00966` should be read in as the string `"00966"`, not the integer `966`.

I know that `SemanticImport` provides ways to specify the types for individual columns, but I want to avoid `SemanticImport` at all cost, because I've found it to be horribly buggy.

Is there some way to get `Import` to just read each line as a list of strings (by doing nothing more to each line than stripping the trailing newline, and splitting the remainder at the tabs)?

Comment: Does the option `"Numeric"->False`, help? That is, does  `Import[path, "tsv", "Numeric"->False]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation >> TSV  >> Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/TSV.html):

- *With "Numeric"-> False, numbers will be imported as strings in the form they appear in the file.*

So, you can use

```
Import[path, "tsv", "Numeric" -> False]
```